# React pass event and parameter on anchor element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `anchor` element in react component, I want to pass event and parameter for it. Below code did not work. It throws `e.preventDefault();` not function error. How can I do this?

```
loadComponent(e, component) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ componentToLoad: component });
}

<a onClick={() => this.loadComponent(this.event, <FormatName />)}>
  Format Name
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `onClick={e => this.loadComponent(e, <FormatName />)}`.

Your `setState` is wrong too:

```
this.setState({ componentToLoad: component });
```

Also, it might be better to store a state that controls the visibility of the component rather than the entire component in the state, then do conditional rendering in `render`:

```
{this.state.showComponent && <FormatName />}
```

Comment: sorry I commented on wrong person, I will try it now.

Comment: I have one question about holding Component in state, wouldn't it be cached in the memory and re-used? Like request("React") and it will be used all over the place? Or it will create copy for each?

Comment: What's `request("React")`? When you render multiple identical components, each of them will be a separate instance (otherwise they'll share the same state etc). Object prototypes are singletons though. Anyway, storing components in state is almost certainly a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

It can be `onClick={() => this.loadComponent(<FormatName />)`

the event will always come as the first parameter to your handler function

`loadComponent(e, component) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({componentToLoad = component});
  }`

Comment: This won't work, you will execute the function on render instead of passing it as a callback.